# Unable to pass Boolean variable value into another express file

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to pass a Boolean value from one file to another in a Node.js application.

**auth.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

var isLoggedIn = false;

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("pages/auth");
    console.log(isLoggedIn);
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.password == "Secret") {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        res.redirect('/home');
    } else {
        res.send("<h1 align='center'>Wrong password</h1>");
    }
    console.log(isLoggedIn);
});

module.exports = {
    auth: router,
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
};
```

If the password is correct, the value of `isLoggedIn` should be *true* but if I import it in another file, it turns *false*.
How do I fix this?

> I don't mind installing another package.

Comment: This wrong for multiple reasons, but one important one to think about is: what will happen if a user logs in and then another user opens the page? What you are looking for are sessions.

Comment: I am not building this for many people. It's just for a few people

Comment: That won't stop automated attackers from taking over your site. The few selected friends you invite to your party are not the problem, the people you _didn't_ invite and who show up anyway are. Especially since now you built it so that the first person opening the door to your house will just keep it open for everyone else, invited or not.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating and exporting the object at the moment the server starts up - and at the moment the server starts up (that is, that the top-level code here runs), the value assigned to `isLoggedIn` is `false`.

While you could kind of fix it by exporting a function that, when called, returns the value of the variable:

```
module.exports = {
    auth: router,
    getIsLoggedIn: () => isLoggedIn,
};
```

A more fundamental problem is that the variable is being set *for the lifetime of the server* being online, for all users. If, for example, user A logs in, unregistered person B who accesses the website from some other browser halfway around the world shouldn't be seen as logged in. The `isLoggedIn` variable should be ditched entirely (unless the logic you *want* is that once one person logs in, the server sees everyone hitting your endpoints as being logged in - which sounds very unusual).

Use something like [session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40755854) instead, so each person accessing the website has separate settable and retrievable state.